# PLSSQL how to convert any result to opposite sign

Tags: plsql

PLSSQL how to convert any result to opposite sign if the result i have in subtracting 2 items is negative-convert it to positive and if result is positive then convert to negative automatically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just multiply with `-1`.

Comment: thanks,,haven't thought about that, thanks a lot